# Show $\bigcap_{\beta\in I}B_{\beta}$ with $B_{\beta}=[-1,\beta)$ with $I=\mathbb{R}^+$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We suppose that $I=\mathbb{R}^+$ and $B_{\beta}=[-1,\beta), \beta\in I$. I calculate and show for the union, i.e., $$\bigcup_{\beta\in I} B_\beta=[-1,+\infty)$$
However, I need to do the same for the intersection. I calculate: $$\bigcap_{\beta\in I} B_\beta=[-1,0]$$
I appreciate your ideas with the proof.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Can you prove it? It's easy to show that $[-1,0]\subset B_\beta$ for every $\beta$, and thus, $[0,1]\subset\bigcap B_\beta$. The other direction is a bit more interesting. For any $r\in\mathbb R\setminus[-1,0]$, can you find some $\beta\in[-1,\infty)$ such that $r\notin B_\beta$?

Comment: Hi Jodie. How did you show your answer for the union? Did you choose an arbitrary element, to begin?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I choose $x$ in the generalized union, for that, exist $\beta\in I$ such as $x\in B_{\beta}$. For the other side, I use the Archimedean property.

Comment: @Jodie As a nitpick, you don't need the Archimedean property (that's overkill in my mind). All you need is that there is no maximal element in $[-1,\infty)$.